# Building equal number of records list object

Tags: c#, .net-datatable

I am trying to get equal number of records in both columns, even if that means that first column doesn't fill page to bottom on the second page. The only way I was able to do this was by using a maxrow count and breaking when it is equal to the max row count.

```
 public List<DataForExcelExport> GetData()
        {

            var list = new List<DataForExcelExport>();
            int ROWS_PER_PAGE = 41;
            int MaxRow = 0;

            SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommandText, connectionString);
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            bool flgLastPage = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                DataRow dr = dataTable.Rows[i];
                var item = new DataForExcelExport();
                SetItemData(dr, item, true);
                if (i + ROWS_PER_PAGE < dataTable.Rows.Count)
                {
                    SetItemData(dataTable.Rows[i + ROWS_PER_PAGE], item, false);
                }
                list.Add(item);
                if (flgLastPage == false)
                {
                    if ((i + 1) % ROWS_PER_PAGE == 0)
                    {
                        i += ROWS_PER_PAGE;

                        int remaining = dataTable.Rows.Count - (i + 1);
                        if (remaining < 2 * ROWS_PER_PAGE)
                        {
                            ROWS_PER_PAGE = remaining / 2 + remaining % 2;
                            flgLastPage = true;

                        }
                    }
                }
                int maxrow = i + ROWS_PER_PAGE;
                if (maxrow == dataTable.Rows.Count)
                {
                    break;

                }
            }
            return list;

        }
```

expected output: when there are a total of 118 rows

```
- page 1 
_________
  1 | 41
... |...
 38 | 78
 39 | 79
 40 | 80
_________

- page 2
_________
 81 | 99
 82 | 100
... | ...
98  |118
_________
```

Comment: It is not easy to understand this code. I think there is too many variables changing their values while you are loading your data. My advice is - as you know `dataTable.Rows.Count` and `ROWS_PER_PAGE` you can calculate the number of pages, and number of rows on the given page in advance, then process things with 2 loops. One for pages, one for rows

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you posted the whole program. So am I correct in now assuming you want 80 entries per page?

Comment: Hey there, looks like you're having login issues; feel free to [contact the community team](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/contact) if you would like your two accounts merged.

Comment: @T145 correct page 1 should display 80 rows and then the remaining should display on page 2

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 3):

Try following some simple rules: Avoid setting flags in loops. Try calculating the data you need before taking action. Only increment counters inside loop declaration. This way even if something gets broken - you will not have to wonder "how did we end up here?". Instead you will be able to tell "this index / limit is not calculated correctly".

Also when saying

> even if that means that first column doesn't fill page to bottom on the second page

Did you mean:

> even if that means both columns don't fill the last page to the bottom

This is how I understood it.

```
int ROWS_PER_PAGE = 41;
int totalDataCount = dataTable.Rows.Count;
int pagesToProcess = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalDataCount / 2.0 / ROWS_PER_PAGE);
int itemsPerPage = ROWS_PER_PAGE * 2;

for(int pageIdx = 0; pageIdx < pagesToProcess; pageIdx++)
{
    int itemsOnThisPage = (pageIdx + 1) * itemsPerPage >= totalDataCount ? totalDataCount - pageIdx * itemsPerPage : itemsPerPage;
    int rowsOnThisPage = (int)Math.Ceiling( itemsOnThisPage / 2.0 );
    for( int rowIdx = 0; rowIdx < rowsOnThisPage; rowIdx++)
    {
        var item = new DataForExcelExport();
        int itemIdx1 = pageIdx * itemsPerPage + rowIdx;
        int itemIdx2 = itemIdx1 + rowsOnThisPage;
        SetItemData(dataTable.Rows[itemIdx1], item, true);
        if(totalDataCount > itemIdx2)
            SetItemData(dataTable.Rows[itemIdx2], item, false);
    }
}
```

Ah yes, and try to name variables in a meaningful way. Names like `i` or `maxrow` do not tell what the variable is really used for.

Comment: I get an error about can't convert double to int on the second line

Comment: On the `Math.Ceiling`? There might be a cast needed, try  `=(int)Math.Ceiling(...)`.

Comment: @jakubiszon I dont get out of the innter for loop? when do I add the item to the list?

Comment: After processing page 1 it set itemsOnThisPage back to 82 and rowsOnThisPage to 41 should that just be the remaining because then itemIdx1 should be 42 it goes back to 0

Comment: 1) What do you mean by not getting out of the inner for loop? Not using `break`? No it is not needed. Break is used when you meet an unforseen condition. There is nothing unforseen to happen here.

Comment: 2) adding an item to the list - you mean this part `var item = new DataForExcelExport`? It happens per each two items, so it should be added in the inner loop.

Comment: When the app starts the values of the objects are totalDataCount = 124, pagesToProcess = 2 and itemsPerPage = 82, that looks correct for page 1. But then on page 2 loop pagesToProcess is increase to 3 is that correct?

Comment: Oh my. You are right. It is `pageIdx` which should be incremented. Correcting it now.

Comment: hmmm from record 52 to 62 it just fills in ColumnOne

Comment: This `int itemIdx1 = pageIdx * itemsPerPage + rowIdx * 2;` should be `int itemIdx1 = pageIdx * itemsPerPage + rowIdx;` I just corrected it.

Comment: btw. If it was difficult to figure out how my quickly skeched up code should work - this is why programmers need to write readable code and give variables good names.

Answer (score 1):

Because this function is presented w/out a context to adequately test the code in, i.e. with sample data, a `Main` function, etc., the best way to critique this presently is against the design.

Let us apply some basic formatting so we can actually get a better idea of what's going on:

```
public List<DataForExcelExport> GetData()
{
    var list = new List<DataForExcelExport>();
    int ROWS_PER_PAGE = 41;
    int MaxRow = 0;

    var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selectCommandText, connectionString);
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
    bool flgLastPage = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dataTable.Rows[i];
        var item = new DataForExcelExport();
        SetItemData(dr, item, true);

        if (i + ROWS_PER_PAGE < dataTable.Rows.Count)
        {
            SetItemData(dataTable.Rows[i + ROWS_PER_PAGE], item, false);
        }

        list.Add(item);

        if (flgLastPage == false)
        {
            if ((i + 1) % ROWS_PER_PAGE == 0)
            {
                i += ROWS_PER_PAGE;

                int remaining = dataTable.Rows.Count - (i + 1);
                if (remaining < 2 * ROWS_PER_PAGE)
                {
                    ROWS_PER_PAGE = remaining / 2 + remaining % 2;
                    flgLastPage = true;
                }
            }
        }

        int maxrow = i + ROWS_PER_PAGE;

        if (maxrow == dataTable.Rows.Count)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

Ah, that's better. Now, to me, the orphaned variables `selectCommandText` and `connectionString` appear as though they're global constants since they are not parameters. If they are, they should look like `COMMAND_TEXT` and `CONNECTION` to align w/ C# standards. There are also other instances of poor variable casing and naming throughout this function. `ROWS_PER_PAGE` is cased as a local constant, which should hopefully sound like an oxymoron. This variable is even modified later on. It should be named something like `pageCap` or `pageLim`. Up next, we have `MaxRow`, which isn't even used. If it were, rather than being PascalCase, it should be CamelCase to align w/ C# standards for variables. I'd say `dataAdapter` and `dataTable` should just be `adapter` and `table`, since we already know what they're doing in this context. Now, applying these changes, we get:

```
public List<DataForExcelExport> GetData()
{
    var list = new List<DataForExcelExport>();
    int pageLim = 41;

    var adapter = new Sqladapter(selectCommandText, connectionString);
    var table = new table();
    adapter.Fill(table);
    bool flgLastPage = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = table.Rows[i];
        var item = new DataForExcelExport();
        SetItemData(dr, item, true);

        if (i + pageLim < table.Rows.Count)
        {
            SetItemData(table.Rows[i + pageLim], item, false);
        }

        list.Add(item);

        if (flgLastPage == false)
        {
            if ((i + 1) % pageLim == 0)
            {
                i += pageLim;

                int remaining = table.Rows.Count - (i + 1);
                if (remaining < 2 * pageLim)
                {
                    pageLim = remaining / 2 + remaining % 2;
                    flgLastPage = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if ((i + pageLim) == table.Rows.Count)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return list;
}
```

The looping is pretty straightforward; you just want to get a certain number of data entries w/in a page limit. To that extent, you could just do something like this:

```
int pageLim = 80;

for (int i = 0; i < pageLim && i < table.Rows.Count; ++i)
{
    // set up `item` var using `row`
    list.Add(item);
}
```

This will create a single item page. Now, if you want multiple pages, I'd suggest looking into a [Dictionary](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) rather than using index-modulo magic in a flat list. This way, you can have page names rather than just page numbers, or any other object. If all you'll use are page numbers, a multi-dimensional list should suffice. That would look something like this:

```
int i = -1;
int pageLim = 80;
List pages = new List();
List page = new List();

foreach (var row in table.Rows)
{
    ++i;

    // set up `item` var using `row`

    if (i < pageLim) {
        page.Add(item);
    } else if (i == (pageLim - 1) || i == (table.Rows.Count - 1)) {
        page.Add(item); // add the last item
        pages.Add(page);
        page.clear();
        i = -1;
    }
}
```

Then just return `pages`, a list of lists w/ at most 80 items per page, and access a page like `pages[0]`. If pages have a lot of metadata, creating a `Page` object and just having a flat list of that is also possible.