# C# Better logic for viewmodel

Tags: c#

Any advice on how to make this code; cleaner, more effective, just overall better!

Program setup object that is coming from the database. it loop the object adding to the viewmodel object. Then the object has a certain properties base on type. The config type will only have the setting and value objects.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Setting up fake objects
        List<Meeting> meetingList = new List<Meeting>();
        meetingList.Add(new Meeting() { Id =1 ,Name="a", Type= "System"  });
        meetingList.Add(new Meeting() { Id = 2, Name = "b", Type = "System" });
        meetingList.Add(new Meeting() { Id = 3, Name = "c", Type = "Config", Setting="Control", Value="2"  });
        meetingList.Add(new Meeting() { Id = 4, Name = "d", Type = "Config", Setting = "Control", Value = "3" });
        meetingList.Add(new Meeting() { Id = 5, Name = "e", Type = "Config", Setting = "", Value = "" });

        //Real Code
        List<Meeting> meetingviewmodel = new List<Meeting>();
        foreach (var meeting in meetingList)
        {
           Meeting mvm = new Meeting();
           meeting.Id = mvm.Id;
           meeting.Name = mvm.Name;
           meeting.Type = mvm.Type;
           if (meeting.Type == "System")
           {
               meetingviewmodel.Add(mvm);
           }
           if (meeting.Type == "Config" && meeting.Setting != null)
           {
              meeting.Setting = mvm.Setting;
              meeting.Value = mvm.Value;
              meetingviewmodel.Add(mvm);

            }
        }
    }

    class Meeting
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Setting { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: [As you've been warned before](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/231488/building-equal-number-of-records-list-object#comment454260_231488) Please stop updating the code in your post. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) as well as  [_what you may and may not do after receiving answers_](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765).

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I think you've flipped the assigning without noticing that you're assigning `null` values to the `meeting` properties (e.g `meeting.Id = mvm.Id;`) notice that you've already create a new instance of `Meeting` object, and yet, you replaced the actual values with the new instance values, while you are expected to do the opposite.

So, I assumed you meant to do this `mvm.Id = meeting.Id;`.

If you need to add the `Meeting` object to the model based on the `Type` property. You can do this :

```
foreach (var meeting in meetingList)
{
    // if this element's Type property is null or empty
    // then skip and go to the next one
    // this condition will be applied on all meeting types 
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(meeting.Type)) { continue; }
    
    meetingviewmodel.Add(meeting);  
}
```

this will add all meeting objects that have defined Type, this will include System and Config types along with any other defined types.

if you only need to add System and Config types  meetings, and ignore the rest, you can do this :

```
foreach (var meeting in meetingList)
{
    // if you want to only add System & Config meetings 
    // you can use this condition
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(meeting.Type) && (meeting.Type == "System" || meeting.Type == "Config"))
    {
        meetingviewmodel.Add(meeting);
    }
}
```

or if you into LINQ :

```
var meetingviewmodel = meetingList
            .Where(x=> !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Type) && (x.Type == "System" || x.Type == "Config"))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: what if the setting and value are null if the type is system ? That’s why I did the two if statement .

Comment: Sorry I mean only add it to the view model when it is not null. So I need to make sure they have values before adding it to the view model

Comment: @Jefferson no, I apology for any inconvenience I caused you. It was my fault, I was not paying attention since I didn't have my coffee when I wrote my answer :(. I updated my answer for that.

Comment: Thanks but that will still add id 5 right , because Id 5 is null for setting it should skip it

Comment: so the meetingviewmodel should only have ids 1-4

Comment: @Jefferson yes, it'll add it, if you want to skip it, add a condition on setting like `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(meeting.Type) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(meeting.Setting))`

Comment: @Jefferson same thing on the value or any property that you want to skip if it's null or empty.